# Script to toggle default web browser (Chrome, IE, Edge)?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, batch, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Certain (company) websites work better with certain web browsers.  I would like a way to switch between Edge, IE, and Chrome on the fly (for opening hyperlinks).  Since Windows 10 is not set up to be able to determine this by website (kind of like Android and apps), so the next best thing would be able to change default browsers on the fly using a shortcut to something like a script or batch file (I would do this right before clicking on a hyperlink such as in an Outlook email).

I found one that changes default browser to IE. It works great, however, I am not sure how to change it to work for the other web browsers, nor have I been able to find one.  How do you do this?

This is the batch file I have for setting IE as the default browser:

```
echo off
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM -- check XHTML support (IE 9+)
set xhtml=0
for /f %%G in ('"reg query "HKCR\IE.AssocFile.XHT" /ve 2>&1 | findstr /c:".XHT" "') do set xhtml=1

REM -- reset file extensions
set exts=HTM,HTML
if %xhtml% == 1 (set exts=%exts%,XHT,XHTML)

for %%G in (%exts%) do (
set ext=%%G
set ext=!ext:~0,3!
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\.%%G" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "IE.AssocFile.!ext!" /f >nul
)

set exts=%exts%,MHT,MHTML,URL
set acl=%temp%\acl_%random%%random%.txt

for %%G in (%exts%) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.%%G\UserChoice
echo !key! [1 7 17]>"%acl%"
regini "%acl%" >nul
set ext=%%G
set ext=!ext:~0,3!
reg add "!key!" /v "Progid" /t REG_SZ /d "IE.AssocFile.!ext!" /f >nul
)
del "%acl%" 2>nul

REM -- reset MIME associations
for %%G in (message/rfc822,text/html) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\MIMEAssociations\%%G\UserChoice
reg add "!key!" /v "Progid" /t REG_SZ /d "IE.%%G" /f >nul
)

REM -- reset URL protocols
for %%A in (FTP,HTTP,HTTPS) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\%%A\UserChoice
reg add "!key!" /v "Progid" /t REG_SZ /d "IE.%%A" /f >nul
for %%B in (DefaultIcon,shell) do (
set key=HKCU\Software\Classes\%%A
reg delete "!key!\%%B" /f >nul 2>&1
reg copy "HKCR\IE.%%A\%%B" "!key!\%%B" /s /f >nul
reg add "!key!" /v "EditFlags" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f >nul
reg add "!key!" /v "URL Protocol" /t REG_SZ /d "" /f >nul
))

REM -- reset the start menu Internet link (Vista and earlier)
reg add "HKCU\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "IEXPLORE.EXE" /f

REM -- reset cached icons
if %xhtml% == 1 (
ie4uinit -cleariconcache
) else (
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f >nul
start explorer
)

REM pause
REM exit /b

exit
```

Comment: One option, if you only need to be able to open shortcuts, and not actual hyperlinks, would be to associate a new extension (.fxurl or .ieurl or .crurl) with the respective browser.